# Uniqueness criterion for tetration based on signs of derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, tetration, smooth-functions

Consider the fractional iterations of the expontential function denoted

$$ \exp^{[t]}(x) $$

$$ \exp^{[0]}(x) = x $$

$$ \exp^{[t]}(x) = \exp(\exp^{[t-1]}(x) $$

$$ \exp^{[l + m]} = \exp^{[l]}(\exp^{[m]}(x))$$

Where $t,l,m,x$ are real and $t > 0$.

My friend Tommy proposed once a condition for an infinitely differentiable solution.

$t,x$ are real and $t > 0$:

$$ \frac{d^n}{d^n x} \exp^{[t]}(x) > 0 $$

It seems impossible to satisfy for analytic solutions because for $ 0 < t < 1$ we have singularities in the complex plane that force the radius being finite and the signs of the derivatives of the taylor series alternating ( because the singularities have taylor series with alternating signs and near the singularities we must have it too). For instance if you are close to a log singularity your taylor series must eventually copy the sign changes of the logarithm.

However if the bundle of functions $exp^{[t]}$ are nowhere analytic on the real line but infinitely differentiable, this might be true ??

CONJECTURE 1 (existance conjecture)

There exist a bundle of infinitely differentiable functions solution satisfying

$$ \frac{d^n}{d^n x} \exp^{[t]}(x) > 0 $$

CONJECTURE 2 (uniqueness conjecture)

The solution to conjecture 1 is unique (if it exists!) ; there is only one (non-analytic) solution for tetration satisfying the condition

$$ \frac{d^n}{d^n x} \exp^{[t]}(x) > 0 $$

Can we prove conjecture 1 or 2 ?

Is this a very general thing or exclusive for iterations of exponential functions ?
I mean, do many entire functions $g(x)$ with all derivatives positive ( at any $x$) , no real fixpoint ( and thus above $id(x)$ btw )  (like exp) satisfy

$$ \frac{d^n}{d^n x} g^{[t]}(x) > 0 $$

??

If conjecture 1 or 2 fail for function $g(x)$ does it work for some real $v$ and function $g(x) + v$ ??
In particular the function $\exp(x) + v$ ?

Comment: There are some ideas as to constructing a solution explicitly. But that is another topic.

Comment: The odd derivatives might be positive everywhere for Kneser's solution.  The even derivatives change sign starting out negative just as tet(z) starts out negative between -2 and 0.  It may be that the even derivatives only change sign once too, and once they are positive they stay positive.  See #6; #11 https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=33
Interestingly, these computations are for Andrew's slog so this positive odd derivative criteria is probably not a uniqueness criteria.

Comment: The op's question refers to holding t as a constant, so if t=0.5, then we would be studying the half iterate of the exonential; $$ \frac{d^n}{d^n x} \exp^{[0.5]}(x) > 0 $$  I am unaware of any work calculating the derivatives of the half iterate of exp (generated from Kneser for example), or any other fractional iterate, as values of x vary in the complex plane.  Further, interest in the non-analytic $C_\infty$ tetration solutions is an even narrower subtopic...

Comment: Kneser's half iterate has a singularity at the two complex conjugate fixed points where exp(z)=z; L;L*=~0.318+1.337i.  The $Tet^{-1}(z)$ also has singularities at L,L*, and $exp^{[0.5]}(z)=Tet(Tet^{-1}(z)+0.5)$, so the derivatives are governed by that singularity.

Comment: I don't have it at hand (and I'm lazy to search) but I think there was a question by Vladimir Reshetnikow (? spelling) in MO with - as I remember - the same focus as your question here. Perhaps to see there what he has found/discussed?

Comment: @Gottfried I was not able to find it. I know WHO you are talking about and found 2 tetration topics but none like the above ?
As far as I know only tommy talked about it. Maybe someone else on the tetration forum. Or maybe in a book from the classic masters ( kneser or so ) . I would be suprised to see this somewhere else.
I could be wrong ofcourse.

Comment: @ Mick - hmm, perhaps my remembering is imprecise. I looked around myself and found this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259278/an-explicit-series-representation-for-the-analytic-tetration-with-complex-height At the end he has conjectures 3 & 4 adressing monotonicity of derivatives and uniqueness which I had stored in my memory roughly in the way you've asked it here. Sorry I can't give better material at this.

Comment: thank you for your comments Gottfriend. That link should have been in my search results but somehow was not. So thank you. I will need to think how that relates.